# How to separate factor interactions in R

Tags: r, tapply, split-apply-combine

I recently had to graph some data based on an interaction of factors and I found it more difficult than I felt something this common should be in R.  I suspect I'm missing something.  Let's say I have a vector of 30 numbers along with a pair of factors.

```
n <- runif(30, min=0, max=10)
a <- gl(2, 1, 30)
b <- gl(6, 2, 30)
```

And I want the mean for each combination of factors.

```
y <- tapply(n, a:b, mean)
```

Now I want to use a lattice **xyplot** to plot these means where I have a panel for each of the two values of `a`.  The means are the `y` values and the `b` factors are the `x` values.  The stock **xyplot** formula would be something like

```
xyplot( y ~ b | a, data=mydf)
```

where `mydf` is a data frame with columns `y`, `b`, and ,`a` that were computed from **tapply** above.  But my problem is how to disentangle the interacting factors.  This is what I did.

```
factorSplit <- strsplit(names(y), ":")
a1 <- sapply(factorSplit, function(x) {x[1]})
b1 <- sapply(factorSplit, function(x) {x[2]})
mydf <- data.frame(y, b1, a1)
```

Now `mydf` has

```
> mydf
           y b1 a1
1:1 3.856797  1  1
1:2 3.487181  2  1
1:3 8.411425  3  1
1:4 3.757709  4  1
1:5 4.982970  5  1
1:6 6.480346  6  1
2:1 2.778864  1  2
2:2 4.390511  2  2
2:3 7.119926  3  2
2:4 4.707945  4  2
2:5 5.546894  5  2
2:6 8.984631  6  2
```

and I can plot with

```
xyplot(y ~ b1 | a1, mydf, layout=c(1,2))
```

But I feel this business with **strsplit** of `names(y)` and then **sapply** is overkill.  It seems there should be a more direct method to recover a factor interaction created with **tapply**.

Comment: Since you want to preserve your `a` and `b` columns, it's better to use `aggregate` here than `tapply`: `y <- aggregate(n~a+b, NULL, mean)`

Comment: `aggregate` is pretty nice. When base grouping gets too confusing, though, I usually turn to `dplyr`, which makes it pretty straightforward. In this case, `data_frame(n, a, b) %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(y = mean(n))`

Comment: Rather than updating the question with a solution, you should post it as an answer below (it's fine to answer your own questions) because that way the question no longer appears unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The **aggregate** function is just what my understanding was lacking.  As pointed out in the comments, one call to **aggregate** does everything I was slogging through earlier.

```
> x <- aggregate(n ~ a+b, NULL, mean)
> head(x)
  a b        n
1 1 1 2.967073
2 2 1 3.001279
3 1 2 3.867564
4 2 2 1.076378
5 1 3 2.805827
6 2 3 6.275858
> dim(x)
[1] 12  3
>
```